# Why is the !important required?

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I believe the specificity is right, and I checked the compiled CSS, but I have to include the !important for this to work. I'm getting kind of angry because of this to be frank. Any help will be greatly appreciated, and feel free to help me clean up some of the other code too, I know it's not perfect :)

```
// Content
.section {
  padding: clamp(50px, 5vh, 200px) 0;

  .section__content {
    width: clamp(300px, 60vw, 100vw);
    margin: 0 auto;

    h2 {
      font-family: $ff-header;
      font-size: clamp(24px, 1.1vw + 1rem, 50px);
      margin-bottom: 1.3rem;
      line-height: 1;
    }

    p {
      font-family: $ff-content;
      font-size: 1rem;
      line-height: 120%;
    }

    &.section--hasImage {
      display: flex;
      gap: 2rem;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;

      .col {
        width: 45%;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Breakpoints
@media (max-width: 50em) {
  .hero {
    justify-content: center;

    .hero__content {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;

      h1 {
        font-size: clamp(30px, 10vw + 1rem, 2000px);
      }

      p {
        font-size: clamp(24px, 1vw + 1rem, 1800px);
      }
    }
  }

  section > .section__content {
    width: clamp(10px, 85vw, 85vw);

    &.section--hasImage {
      display: block !important;

      .col {
        width: 100% !important;

        &:last-of-type {
          margin-top: 2rem;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can always check the browsers' Developer Console to see which CSS selector is overriding the concerned CSS property before you add the `!important`.

Comment: `.section` beats `section` if both match.